# Preview post functionality (like in Wordpress) in a Laravel's blog

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to add to my Laravel's blog app the ability to open a preview of a post in a new window/tab before saving it to the DB (like in Wordpress). Which is the best way to do it?

I've been reading a few posts about it, and for now I've tried something like this:

When I click the 'Preview' button in my create post view I make an ajax call to the store method, which will return a laravel's blade rendered view...

```
$('.preview-post').click(function () {
    var formData = $('#post-form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/posts/store',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData
    }).done(function (response) {
        var w = window.open();
        w.document.write(response);
    });
});
```

Here's the method in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = $title;
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(view('home.posts.ajax-post', compact('post'))->render());
    }
}
```

As you can see, for the moment I've just included the title field, not the whole post, just to check if it works.

Finally, here's the view I'm returning and opening in a new window:

```
@extends('layouts.home')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="post-content">
                    {{$post->title}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

So that's it. The problem is: it seems to work (I'm able to get the view in a new tab with the expected title I typed in the form field), but I guess I'm doing something wrong, because I have for example some animated svg elements that don't render in the proper way in the new window. I've also started with Laravel Framework like a month ago, so I don't know if I'm following the correct workflow to do something like this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself first?

Comment: Yep, I've edited the question...

Comment: I would consider adding a published field to your table. Also, can you post the code that's generating the svg elements?